how to maintain personal devcontainer configuration in a forked repository
I would like to use the GitHub Codespaces feature to develop an open-source project on GitHub. However, this project does not have a maintained devcontainer configuration, and I am not going to include my devcontainer configuration (not only dependencies for development, but also commonly used development tools for myself) to the upstream repository via a Pull Request.
What would be the best practices or optimized workflow for me in this scenario?
The solution I have come up with at the moment is as follows:

create a commit to submit my devcontainer configuration into the dev branch

develop in the dev branch with multiple commits

create a pull request branch which cherry picks all dev commits without the first devcontainer commit


Or, create a branch to save my devcontainer configuration, and switch to the dev branch in codespace after the contianer is created.
I'd like to keep my devcontainer configuration as a drop-in to the forked repo.
